# SetPerTcpConnectionEStats and GetPerTcpConnectionEStats is returning error code 1214 (invalid NETNAME)

Tags: windows, winapi, tcp, tcpdump

I am trying to get stats similar to the ones shown in "Resource Monitor" in windows in a my c++ service. For that I have used the example shown at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getpertcp6connectionestats?redirectedfrom=MSDN. But I am stuck because SetPerTcpConnectionEStats  and GetPerTcpConnectionEStats is returning with error code 1214. The only difference btn. the code in the example at above mentioned link and mine is that I am not working on a particular local and remote port but on all the entries in the tcp table, but I don't think that should make any difference.

Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this error if I work with all the entries. According to the sample you linked, in addition to local and remote port, `GetTcpRow` has a search parameter [`MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tcpmib/ns-tcpmib-mib_tcprow_lh). The state is the normal state for the data transfer phase of the TCP connection.

The following sample works for me.

```
DWORD RunEstatsTest(bool v6) //set as IPv4(FALSE)
{
    PMIB_TCPTABLE tcpTable = NULL;

    DWORD status, size = 0;

    status = GetTcpTable(tcpTable, &size, TRUE);
    if (status != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
        return status;
    }
    tcpTable = (PMIB_TCPTABLE)malloc(size);
    if (tcpTable == NULL) {
        return ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
    status = GetTcpTable(tcpTable, &size, TRUE);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        free(tcpTable);
        return status;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tcpTable->dwNumEntries; i++) {
        if (MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB == tcpTable->table[i].State)
        {
            ToggleAllEstats(&tcpTable->table[i], TRUE, v6);

            GetAllEstats(&tcpTable->table[i], v6);

            ToggleAllEstats(&tcpTable->table[i], FALSE, v6);
        }
    }
    free(tcpTable);
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and this solved the issue. I was going through the table and could see that for all the entries which have state not equal to  MIB_TCP_STATE_ESTAB and remoteAddr and remoteSocket as 0. Any idea about the use of such entries in this table?